# Within a string, how to check whether the previous character ahead of another one is a space?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Am facing a situation that is hard to describe. Will explain and correct me if am wrong

I do have a string

```
String 1 - I am: learning javascript ( no space before : )
String 2 - I am: learning javascript (1 space after : )
```

Condition am doing is first I need to check whether a string has 1 colon only if the string has only **1 colon**, if so, then check whats the element coming in front of colon, if it does have space don't do anything  and if it ** doesn't have space**, add a space

I got the occurrence of finding 1 colon in a string like

```
  term.indexOf(':') === term.lastIndexOf(':')) ||
 (term.match(new RegExp(":", "g")) || []).length===1) {
```

But I am not getting whats the character coming ahead of the colon, if it %20 (space), don't do anything, if **NOT** %20 ( i mean not space) **ADD** a space

Am sorry if any confusions happen, I can explain if any more info is needed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with [a regex which captures](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#capturing-groups-in-replacement) both the optional whitespace (also as sequence) and the colon ...

[/(\s*)(:)/g](https://regex101.com/r/TeM4Hu/1)

The callback function of `replace` gets [passed as its arguments ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

1. the entire match ... e.g. either `'   :'` or just `':'`
2. the 1st capture for the whitespace ... e.g. either `'   '` or just `''`
3. the 2nd capture for the colon ... of cause always `':'`

Thus within a callback function one can test for the existence of whitespace(s).

```js
function replaceWsColonGroup(match, space, colon) {
  console.log({ match, space, colon });
  return (space || " ") + colon;
}
const regXWsColonGroup = (/(\s*)(:)/g);

console.log(
  ' I am: learning javascript =>\n',
  'I am: learning javascript'.replace(regXWsColonGroup, replaceWsColonGroup),
  '\n\n'
);
console.log(
  ' I am : learning javascript =>\n',
  'I am : learning javascript'.replace(regXWsColonGroup, replaceWsColonGroup),
  '\n\n'
);
console.log(
  ' I am\n\t: learning javascript =>\n',
  'I am\n\t: learning javascript'.replace(regXWsColonGroup, replaceWsColonGroup),
  '\n'
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

And regarding the OP's first condition, checking the existence of just a single colon, I suggest a [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) based approach which splits the string at every existing colon and then just checks the resulting array's `length` property that's value then needs to be exactly `2`.

```js
console.log(
  "... valid ...\n",
  "'I am: learning javascript'.split(':').length ...",
  'I am: learning javascript'.split(':').length  
);
console.log(
  "... invalid ...\n",
  "'I: am: learning javascript'.split(':').length ...",
  'I: am: learning javascript'.split(':').length  
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Thus, a sanitizer script would look pretty much like the following one ...

```js
function sanitizeExpression(str) {
  return (String(str).split(':').length === 2)
    ? String(str)
        .replace((/(\s*)(:)/g), (_, $1, $2) => ($1 || ' ') + $2)
    : str
}

console.log(
  sanitizeExpression()
);
console.log(
  sanitizeExpression(null)
);

console.log(
  sanitizeExpression('foo bar baz')
);
console.log(
  sanitizeExpression('I:am:learning javascript')
);

console.log(
  sanitizeExpression('I am: learning javascript')
);
console.log(
  sanitizeExpression('I am\n\t: learning javascript')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use:

```
^([^:]*(?<!\s)):([^:]*)$
```

This would check if a string only contains a single colon that is not preceded by a space character. The different parts are captured in groups so you can replace this by:
`$1 :$2`.

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6OvT8v/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(` - Open 1st capture group:

  - `[^:]*` - 0+ times any character other than colon.
  - `(?<!\s)` - A negative lookbehind to prevent a preceded whitespace.
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group.
- `:` - Match a colon.
- `(` - Open 2nd capture group:

  - `[^:]*` - 0+ times any character other than colon.
  - `)` - Close 2nd capture group.
- `$` - End string anchor.

```js
const regex = /^([^:]*(?<!\s)):([^:]*)$/;

[
  "I am: learning javascript",
  "I am : learning javascript"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(regex, "$1 :$2")));
```

Comment: i understood the demo , but code wise can you help me how to return the same using the same regex ?

Comment: @Coder, JS is not my forte, but to get an idea you could use the code generator if you follow my link. It will be a button on the left panel under "Tools".

Comment: I completely understand , but was looking for a regex converter code, regex will take input string and will convert to new string as per regex

Comment: (Just for fun, I found one with a single group :-) https://regex101.com/r/ttZZsg/1)

Comment: Nice @TheFourthBird. Thanks for the edit. I am currently not on my pc but I just also thought it's possible to replace the negative lookbehind with an simple `\S`....right?

Comment: Yes I think so, if the `:` can not be at the start of the string, you can use `[^\s:]` to match anything except a whitespace char or `:`

Answer (score 0):

If string has only 1 colon, if so ,then check whats the element coming in front of colon , if it do have space dont do anything and if it dont have space , add a space

Javascript code -

```
var term= "I am: learning javascript ";
if(term.indexOf(':') === term.lastIndexOf(':')) {

      var indexOfColon = term.indexOf(':');
      var nextChar = term.charAt(indexOfColon + 2);
     
      if(nextChar != ' '){
               
               term = term.slice(0,indexOfColon+1) + ' ' + term.slice(indexOfColon+1)
       }
}
console.log(term) ==> "I am:  learning javascript ";
```

Added a space after colon.

Comment: i should have one space preceeding colon if it dont have space